# Mixing Essentials and Core D&D, is it ok?

Tags: dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How compatible are D&D 4th Edition and Essentials? Can you use Essentials encounters with 4th edition characters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4582/how-compatible-are-dd-4th-edition-and-essentials-can-you-use-essentials-encoun)

Here is my situation, I wanted to get my daughter and siblings started on RPG (11-14 y.o.), so I got the Dungeon Master's Kit, Monster Vault and HOTFL/HOTFK books. The only problem was that the books are in english, not our main language. I'm used to it and I learned to play RPG with english books so I gave it a shot.

The result was not so great. They got really confused about what was their powers and I literally had to read the all the descriptions to them.

Now, the Player's Handbook are translated to our primary language, together with the many pages of errata (the reason that I avoided it in the first place).

Can I buy the PH and give it to my players while I use the DMK and MV? What would be the expected problems and diferences?

Comment: This looks a lot like http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4582/how-compatible-are-dd-4th-edition-and-essentials-can-you-use-essentials-encoun/

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8552/which-4e-books-are-made-obsolete-by-essentials-releases/ is also related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core 4e and Essentials 4e **are** compatible.

The main issue you might be concerned about is that core 4e classes have considerably more powers, and are in general more complex, than Essentials classes. If the powers being in English is the main problem, then having a translated book will help. If simply keeping track of what their options are is a source of confusion, then switching to their core classes may make things worse.

Comment: The main problem it the language barrier... although, keeping track of the caracteristics of every power was a bit hard also, but the language also contributed to that.

Comment: I'm gonna buy the Player's Handbook and give it another try...